# Is this equation solvable for y?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Is this equation solvable for $y$?

$$x = y + e^{-1.9 + 3.9  \tanh\left(\frac{-(y - 121)}{14}\right)}  (z - 4)^{1.9 + 1.4  \tanh\left(\frac{-(y-121)}{14}\right)}$$

This equation partly describes the nerve fibres that make up our eye, where y is an angle around the optic disc and z is some distance away from the optic disc. x is the angle around the optic disc that the fibre is at that distance (z) and from a particular starting angle (y). What I want is to take an arbitrary angle (x) and distance (z) from the optic disc and see where it started from (y).

Here is the main research paper I am working from:
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2848177/

Thanks for the help everyone!

Comment: you would need to use the weierstrass function :/

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Klangen i don't think there's much to try, as anyone who doesn't know about the Lambert W function would struggle to solve this

Comment: Hi, I'm not mathematically savvy at all so I haven't tried anything in the realms of actually solving for y.

Comment: @SakethMalyala I agree. In this case it would have been preferable to include the comment "*I tried using conventional methods but those methods failed*" in the question.

Comment: Why do you need to?

Comment: @Randall It is for a project I am working on mapping the eye. This equation partly describes the nerve fibres that make up our eye, where y is an angle around a optic disc and z is some distance away from the optic disc. x is the angle around the optic disc that the fibre is at that distance. What I want is to take an arbitrary angle (x) and distance (z) from the optic disc and see where it started from (y). I will update the question to include this information.

Comment: That is legitimately interesting.

Comment: @Randall Thanks! So far, my solution has been to simulate hundreds of nerve fibres around the optic disc and then interpolate values at discrete intervals along them to create a matrix of y values covering the eye, but this is extremely computationally expensive in order to be accurate and still isn't perfect. What would be better is to be able to a take any point and directly be able to calculate it's starting point around the optic disc. Thus the question if y is solvable in this equation.

Comment: @SakethMalyala Sorry, could you explain what the weierstrass/ Lambert W function is and how I would use it?